# How to select an element by using attribute comparsion in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, attributes, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get an element with a child, which has the same name as another node (with a specific condition).
Source:

```
<objects>

  <object>
    <element>
      <type name="thing"></type>
    </element>
  </object>

  <object>
    <prog name="thing">
      <extends>SuperClass</extends>
    </prog>
  </object>

</objects>
```

I want to get an object's element, if its type has the same name as a prog (condition: prog extends "SuperClass") of another object.

My Xpath:

```
./objects/object/element[./type/@name={ancestor::objects/object/prog[./extends/text()='SuperClass']/@name}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get an object's element, if its type has the same name as a prog (condition: prog extends "SuperClass") of another object.

```
//element[type/@name = //prog[extends = 'SuperClass']/@name]
```

*"Select all `<element>` where the `<type>/@name` equals the `@name` of any `<prog>` that contains an `<extends>` equal to `'SuperClass'`"*

You've almost had it. XPath does not have attribute value templates (i.e. expressions in curly braces) - that's an XSLT feature, and not even necessary here. Lose them and it works:

```
./objects/object/element[./type/@name=ancestor::objects/object/prog[./extends/text()='SuperClass']/@name]
```

Once you cut out the fluff (such as the `./` which most of the time is implicit anyway, and the `/text()`, which does something you often don't want), it looks a lot like my expression.

```
//element[type/@name = ancestor::objects//prog[extends='SuperClass']/@name]
```

If you're starting to look at the document root anyway, the `ancestor::` is superfluous, too.

```
//element[type/@name = //prog[extends = 'SuperClass']/@name]
```

...and that's it.